# TV ergonomics in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, television, samsung-smart-tv

Im having fun toying with AIR and want to use it to create an application for my TV, but Im coping with a serious & dumb problem : TV ergonomics. Indeed, without a mouse, it is all about focus on elements and moving this focus in a natural fashion.

In HTML this is handled by the browsers perfectly, but in ActionScript Im having a real hard time ! For instance, I don't even know how to have an element on autofocus, so that when I load the app there is already something to click on (without it I just can't interact with my app at all!).

Do you have any idea on the best ways to create a listener for the remote controller arrows and OK button (should be enough) so that I never get stuck in the app ?

So whether you have already struggled with that or if you simply happen to know how to play with the focus and setFocus() parts of Flex, your help is very welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you look at the [Google TV Flash template](http://code.google.com/p/gtv-resources/wiki/FlashTemplateStarterGuide).  It's all about controls and navigation.  I'm not sure if this works for Flex as I have not done any gtv development yet.

Comment: thanks a lot but the GTV provides its own remote control API. If AIR wants to succeed on TV they'd better step it up with the documentation...

Comment: Yes, I know that.  Google haven't been concentrating a lot on gtv for development of Air and whatnot.  All I can say is start trying it out, put pressure on google/adobe when things get fuzzy and be patient.